# Fetch OptionHash for Regions with Country Filter

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to fetch the list of states/provinces in US, and add it to grid as filter, for my custom module.

I tried the following, and it provides me just a single element in the array, which is the last in the collection.

`Mage::getResourceModel('directory/region_collection')->addCountryFilter('US')->toOptionHash()`

On digging with the method it seems, **`toOptionHash`** method uses **`id`** as default identifier to create array indexes, is there any way out I could get this array, other than looping over the collection or looping over array fetched with **`toOptionArray`**